# Python code for serving k customers with bounded time window

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

As I asked a question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131632/serving-k-customers-with-bounded-time-window), I want to write a python code for the following problem:

A person provides a service and he/she can serve \$k\$ clients each minute. Now, client number \$i\$ comes at the beginning of minute \$ a_{i} \$ and waits \$w_{i}\$ minutes to receive the service and if they don't receive the service in the interval \$[a_{i}, a_{i} + w_{i}]\$, they leave. If we have \$n\$ clients, can the person serve all them or not?

Now, by the answer stated there, I wrote the following code.

```
intervals = [] # Some intervals like [[1, 2], [1, 100], [1, 1], [5, 20]]

intervals = sorted(intervals)

start = intervals[0][0]
end = intervals[-1][1]

i = start
while i < end:
    if not intervals:
        break
    else:
        for j in range(k):
            try:
                if intervals[0][0] <= i <= intervals[0][1]:
                    del intervals[0]
                else:
                    break
            except:
                pass
    i += 1

if not intervals:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

**My question**: Is my code right? Can it become more efficient?

Comment: I'll let one of the python guru's answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Time complexity** is unnecessarily large.

  First, it is linear in the timespan of the arrivals. A list `[[1,2], [100,101]]` would require 100 iterations; a list `[1,2], [1000,1001]]` would require 1000 iterations, etc. Don't bruteforce every minute.

  Second, `del intervals[0]` has a linear time complexity in number of intervals, which results in an overall quadratic time complexity. A cheap way out is to sort in a descending order, and work right to left. This way you would remove intervals from the tail of the list, which is `O(1)`.
- **DRY**. A presence of two semantically identical `break`s (the loop is broken when it runs out of the intervals) suggests refactoring. Do not test for `if not intervals` explicitly. Consider

  ```
    try:
        while i < end:
            for j in range(k):
                if intervals[0][0] <=i <= intervals[0][1]:
                    del intervals[0]
            i += 1
    except:
        pass
  ```

  Of course, never `except` blindly. Catch only exceptions you expect and know how to handle, in this case `except IndexError:`.

Answer (score 0):

By the above instructions, I changed my code as following and it passed all the tests (even time limits exceeded are handled).

```
import sys

n, k = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

intervals = ([int(i) for i in input().split()] for i in range(n))

if k >= n:
    print('YES')
    sys.exit()

intervals = sorted(intervals)
start = intervals[0][0]
end = intervals[-1][1]

i = start

while i < end:

    if intervals[0][1] < i:
        print('NO')
        sys.exit()

    elif len(intervals) <= k * (end - i + 1):
        print('YES')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        for j in range(k):
            if intervals[0][0] <= i <= intervals[0][1]:
                del intervals[0]
            else:
                break
    i += 1

if not intervals:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Thank you all.